# Trigger keyboard interrupt on multiple cell selection in gridcontrol devexpress

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have a wpf application which contains a devexpress gridcontrol.Selection mode of gridcontrol is cell and multiple cells can be selected at once. What I want to achieve is when I shift select multiple rows and press ctrl-d on the keyboard an event should be fired. Basically in this event I want to copy down the cell contents from the topmost cell. Is this possible to be achieved and how?

Answer (score 0):

GridView.GetSelectedCells() returns selected cells in the same order as the cells have been selected by user, so you have to manually find the topmost one in 'ctrl-d clicked' event handler.

Regards,

Maciej Nowicki